# Outdoor water faucet will not stop leaking

Tags: leak, faucet, outdoor

Ive searched online for days and have not found a faucet that looks like mine.  I have tried 2 wrenches, but it still will not budge. Can you tell by looking at the photos if it is soldered? I able to get the handle off, but nothing else will come loose. Now in order to get the least amount of leakage the handle has to be turned in an exact position.  If I turn it all the way off it will leak ALOT.

[image: faucet]
![faucet2][2]
![faucet3][3]
[image: faucet4]

Comment: You've got four image references, but only two links (it could be because higher rep is needed for more images).  If you can add the links for the 2nd and 3rd images in a comment, someone can add them to the post for you.

Comment: Looks like it would be pretty easy to replace that faucet.  Looks like they are around $5 at the big box stores.

Comment: Where do you live? I would like to come to your house and replace that faucet for you, if I can have the old one for my museum.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an early version of a ball valve. To repair it, if you could, you would need to remove the faucet. At that point it would be easier to get a new one to reinstall.

It is a threaded connection on the supply line, possibly 1/2". It will take 2 large pipe wrenches to remove it.

Comment: yup though it looks like it's been there a long time. Liberal application of heat might be required to break the corrosion.